# How to put borders around my output in PHPexcel in a Dynamic way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, phpexcel

Can anyone help me how to put borders around in my output arrays in my report in excel using PHPexcel.

I read the documentation but the example is in Static and you need to set the number already.

I want to do is when all arrays is transferred to excel all of them will have borders.

The problem is my current code is not working can anyone help me with this please.

```
$result = array();

       for ( $n = 1; $n <=35; $n++ ){

        $name = isset($_POST['name'.$n]) ? $_POST['name'.$n] : "";
              if(!$name)
              {
                 continue;
              } 

        $no = 0+$n;
        $aic = isset($_POST['aic'.$n]) ? $_POST['aic'.$n] : "";
        $repcode = isset($_POST['repcode']) ? $_POST['repcode'] : "";
        $optA = isset($_POST['optA'.$n]) ? $_POST['optA'.$n] : "";
        $optB = isset($_POST['optB'.$n]) ? $_POST['optB'.$n] : "";
        $optC = isset($_POST['optC'.$n]) ? $_POST['optC'.$n] : "";
        $optD = isset($_POST['optD'.$n]) ? $_POST['optD'.$n] : "";
        $total = isset($_POST['total'.$n]) ? $_POST['total'.$n] : "";
        $remarks = '';

        $result[] = array(
              $no,
              "PRO13325-".$aic,
              $repcode,
              $name,
              $optA,
              $optB,
              $optC,
              $optD,
              $total,
              $remarks );
        }



$row = 5;
    foreach($result as $rows){
    if (!empty($rows[4])) {
        $borderArray = array(
            'borders' => array(
            'outline' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000'),
                    ),
                ),
            );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, null, 'A' . $row)->applyFromArray($borderArray);
        $row++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$borderArray = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'outline' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000'),
        ),
    ),
);

$row = 5;
foreach($result as $rows){
    if (!empty($rows[4])) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, null, 'A' . $row);
        $row++;
    }
    $columnCount = count($rows);
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A5:' . PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnCount) . $row-1 )
    ->applyFromArray($borderArray);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate -1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eloginko\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:546 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\eloginko\Classes\PHPExcel\Style.php(217): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('-1') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\eloginko\interview.php(188): PHPExcel_Style->applyFromArray(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\eloginko\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 546

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$borderArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,
        'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000')
     )
  )
);

$row = 5;
foreach($result as $rows){
    if (!empty($rows[4])) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $row)->applyFromArray($borderArray);
        $row++;
    }
}
```